# Progress bar not working in html file

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

I am creating a progrees bar is it working fine in jsfiddle demo but when i use in html file it is not working here is my code 
i am writing same code as given in jsfiddle but it is not working

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
  .ui-progressbar.beginning .ui-progressbar-value { background: red; }
  .ui-progressbar.middle .ui-progressbar-value { background: yellow; }
  .ui-progressbar.end .ui-progressbar-value { background: green; }
 </style>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

 </head>


 <script>
  var $progressbar = $("div").progressbar();


  function updateProgressbar(current, target) {


   var value = parseInt(current / target * 100);

   $progressbar

   .progressbar("value", value)

   .removeClass("beginning middle end")


    .addClass(value < 40 ? "beginning" : value < 80 ? "middle" : "end");
  }



  var total = 255;


   var working = 0;





 function update() {

   working++;
 updateProgressbar(working, total);
if (working < total) setTimeout(update, 10);

   }
var $progressbar = $("div").progressbar();

function updateProgressbar(current, target) {


var value = parseInt(current / target * 100);





$progressbar


    .progressbar("value", value)


    .removeClass("beginning middle end")


    .addClass(value < 40 ? "beginning" : value < 80 ? "middle" : "end");


   }





   var total = 255;


  var working = 0;


  function update() {


   working++;




updateProgressbar(working, total);


if (working < total) setTimeout(update, 10);


  }




  </script>
  </head>

<body onload="update()">

<div>


</div></body></html>
```

and here is js fiddle link working

http://jsfiddle.net/ZQrnC/305/

Comment: I think progressbar is part of jqueryui, you're only including the core jquery library.jsfiddle includes the jqueryui library as well looking at the requests. Include jqueryui and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Look in the left sidebar of jsfiddle below "External Resources". You are embedding the jQuery UI css and js for your `progressbar()` there, but your html file jQuery UI is missing.

Add the following after your `jquery-1.9.1.js`-script-tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have added also again they not working can you please edit in complete code so i may add that in new htm file please

Comment: You can see & download the contents of your jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQrnC/305/embedded/result/ (rightclick -> view frame source in Google Chrome) or use this URL: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ZQrnC/305/show/light/

Answer (score 0):

There are three reasons why it does not work:

- As robbi5 stated you don't import the jquery ui JS and CSS files
- Your var $progressbar is initialized in the header when the page is not already loaded and so no div can be found. In other words $progressbar points on nothing
- Your progress bar has an height of zero making it invisble, you should wrap him a container div with a fixed height

Also your code contains duplicate part but it may due to a wrong copy/paste.

Here is an updated working version of your page with the corrected points. I checked rapidly only on chrome and firefox and it works.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
  .ui-progressbar.beginning .ui-progressbar-value { background: red; }
  .ui-progressbar.middle .ui-progressbar-value { background: yellow; }
  .ui-progressbar.end .ui-progressbar-value { background: green; }
 </style>

 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">


     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src=" http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 </head>

 <script>

  var $progressbar;

  function updateProgressbar(current, target) {
       var value = parseInt(current / target * 100);

        $progressbar.progressbar("value", value).removeClass("beginning middle end")
        .addClass(value < 40 ? "beginning" : value < 80 ? "middle" : "end");
  }

  var total = 255;
  var working = 0;

 function update() {
   $progressbar = $("#pbholder").progressbar();
   working++;
   updateProgressbar(working, total);
   if (working < total) setTimeout(update, 10);
  }

  </script>
  </head>

<body onload="update()">

<div id="container" style="height:50px">
    <div id="pbholder"> 
    </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```